# react native 4 item every line for list

Tags: react-native

[image]

like above picture im using a list, but i need that is when i have more that 4 item i need to render after fourth on the second line

here is my mapping and render list code

```
const colorPicker = () => {
    let colorPick = colors.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.pickerDetail}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              setColorPicked(product[index].ColorCode);
            }}>
            <Text> {item} </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
    });
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'flex-start',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          paddingRight: dimensions.width * 0.025,
        }}>
        <ScrollView  >{colorPick}</ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: try having them in a `flex` and user `flex-wrap` property set to `wrap`

Comment: thanks for help guys. i already use the flat list and numColumns props but its too small for flat list. flex-wrap is usefull for me thanks